# Why does't the use of the same number of significant digits result in consistent result?

Tags: measurements

Here is a table:
$
\begin{array}{ c c c c c c c }
 Trial number & Time for 20 cycles & Period & Frequency & Wavelength & Velocity (wavelength*frequency) & Velocity (wavelength/period) \\
 1 & 19.08 & 0.9540 & 1.048 & 8.000 & 8.384 & 8.386 \\
 2 & 10.10 & 0.5050 & 1.980 & 4 & 7.920 & 7.921 \\
 3 & 7.65 & 0.383 & 2.61 & 2.67 & 6.97 & 6.97 \\
 4 & 5.08 & 0.254 & 3.94 & 2.00 & 7.88 & 7.87 
\end{array}
$

I used four significant digits for all the measurements for trial one and two, three significant digits for trails three and four. I thought I was gonna get the same velocity by both methods. But only the velocity results for trail three conform. Why?

Comment: Significant digits are not a valid form of error calculus, even though we teach them in high school (which we shouldn't).

Comment: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/227942/why-are-significant-figure-rules-in-multiplication-division-different-than-in-ad is probably unhelpful.